# LISP &rest issue

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

So I'm new to LISP, and I'm playing with a couple of basic sum functions.

```
(defun suma (&rest L)
  (cond
    ((null L) 0)
    (T (+ (CAR L) (EVAL (CONS 'suma (CDR L)))))
))


(defun suma2 (&rest L)
  (cond
   ((null L) 0)
   (T (+ (car L) (suma2 (cdr L))))
))
```

The first function works just fine.  The second function gives this error: SB-KERNEL::CONTROL-STACK-EXHAUSTED.

My question is: why is the first function ok and the second is not when they are essentially doing the same thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you call, say, `(suma2 1 2 3)`, `L` will be the list `(1 2 3)`. You will then call `(suma2 (cdr L))`, i.e. `(suma2 '(2 3))`. In that invocation `L` will be the list `((2 3))`, i.e. a list containing a single element: the list `(2 3)`. Now it will call `(suma2 (cdr L))` again and this time `(cdr L)` is the empty list, so in the next invocation `L` is a list containing the empty list. Since that's still a list containing one element, it will again recurse and again and again. The case where `L` is empty will never be reached because `L` will always be a list containing exactly one element: the result of `(cdr L)`.

So you should either change your `suma2` function to accept a list instead of a variable number of arguments (and then call it as `(suma2 (list 1 2 3))` or `(suma2 '(1 2 3))` instead  of `(suma2 1 2 3)`) or use `apply` to call `suma2` with the contents of the list as its arguments instead of the list itself.

Answer (score 5):

Your function call in the second function (-> suma2) is wrong.

You expect your function to be called like this:

```
(suma2 1 2 3 4)
```

But the first recursive call is equivalent to this:

```
(suma2 '(2 3 4))
```

You pass a list, where individual elements are expected. See the documentation for `APPLY`.